# Duplicate final declaration, should it be avoided?

Tags: java, final

If we have a private final instance variable to be passed to a private method, do we redeclare it with final modifier in the function when passed as parameter ? eg:

```
public class GraphAlgo {

  private final source;

  public GraphAlgo(source) {
     this.source = source
  }

  public void runAlgo() {
     runAlgoUsingSource(source);
  } 

  private runAlgoUsingSource(final source) {  // here final is declared on a final field
    //-- whatever.
  } 
}
```

Dont declare final for a parameter which is already a final.
Advantage. prevents duplicate final modifier
Disadvantage: Does not provide explicit picture, eg: if GraphAlgo is a 10000 line code then simply looking at the function 'runAlgoUsingSource' he would not have visual access to understand if 'source' was final or not.

Whats the general convention in this case ?

Comment: why would you pass it as a param if it's already a member of the class?

Comment: Please give those variables types, and make sure to fix any other syntax errors to avoid confusion.

Comment: Those two `source` variables are entirely different! `GraphAlgo.source` has nothing to do with `runAlgoUsingSource`'s local variable `source` except that they happen to have the same name. They can have different types, one can be a primitive while the other is a reference, anything goes! It's important you don't confuse them.

Comment: OK, first up, your code isn't valid Java, because you've omitted the type of the `source` instance variable and the `source` parameter.  Secondly, the two `final` declarations actually mean different things.  One means that the instance variable won't change (other than in the constructor and static initialisers); one means that the value of the parameter won't change during the method.

Comment: . Secondly, the two final declarations actually mean different things. One means that the instance variable won't change (other than in the constructor and static initialisers); one means that the value of the parameter won't change during the method -- thanks thats my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, `source` is already an instance variable.  Why pass it to a method?  For that matter, here,

```
private runAlgoUsingSource(final source) {
```

`source` is now another variable, scoped as a local variable, and named the same as your instance variable.  (It also needs a type.)  Whether this local `source` is `final` does not depend on whether `this.source` (the instance variable) is `final`.

Answer (score 3):

No, [Use final liberally](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=23).

One is for an instance variable:

```
private final SomeType source;
```

and the other is for a method:

```
private runAlgoUsingSource(final SomeType source) {
```

The first says that the instance variable cannot be changed (if it's a reference it cannot refer to a different object), the second says that the method argument cannot be changed.

Comment: +1 I actually feel quite strongly that `final` should have been the default with `nonfinal` as the option. Anyways, another use for a `final` local parameter is when you have to reference it from an anonymous inner class declared in that method.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a matter of convention; the two `final` declarations mean different things. Even if the value of a field flows into a parameter, the field can be `final` and the parameter non-`final` or vice versa.

It's a matter of debate, but my view is that you should only declare a parameter `final` if you need to -- and basically the only reason you need to declare a parameter final is if you use its value in an anonymous inner class. Fields, on the other hand, should be `final` unless you explicitly want to modify them.

Answer (score 0):

The two `final` modifiers aren't related. One's making the *instance member* living on the *heap* `final`. The other's making a method's *local variable* (which just happens to share the same name) and is on the *stack* `final`.

Marking a method *local variable* `final` lets JVM optimise certain things (because it now knows the method does not modify it) and is a good practice. Marking the *instance member* `final` goes more on the lines of declaring an actual constant.